# Serving Dropdown from database in every page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

I have this project i'm working on and it has 2 apps.
Main app: which has the pages(Home, About, Contact)
Inventory app: which has the models(Category, Products, Tagging, etc..)

Now the navigation-bar always is always displaying the categories drop-down menu which lists 5 categories or a number of them with a button to see all.

i am using class-based views and i can override the get_context_data method and query the Category model and add it to context on each page render but i was wondering if there is a better method to go about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). It can automatically add data to context, and every template will have access to it. You need to edit your settings.py to include a path to your custom function.

From the docs:

> It’s a Python function that takes one argument, an HttpRequest object, and returns a dictionary that gets added to the template context. Each context processor must return a dictionary.
>
> Custom context processors can live anywhere in your code base. All Django cares about is that your custom context processors are pointed to by the 'context_processors' option in your TEMPLATES setting — or the context_processors argument of Engine if you’re using it directly.

Comment: Yeah. That sounds a lot better. But still it does hit the database every time i load a page.. Correct ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to avoid hitting the database for something like this, you'd need to cache the result. This is a good starting point: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/, and once you set it up, have a look at the usage section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#basic-usage

Comment: I'll take a look at that. Thanks a lot